# Gradle:Build failed: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found after adding api dependencies com.microsoft.service

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build Microsoft Sharepoint client for Lists. In order to do that I am using **Office365** Services library and API. My gradle dependencies look like below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    api 'com.microsoft.aad:adal:2.0.4-alpha'
    api 'com.microsoft.services:sharepoint-services:1.0.0@aar'
    api 'com.microsoft.services.orc:orc-android:1.3.1'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'
}
```

During gradle synch it fails with error:

```
    error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
    Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found., sources=[C:\Users\rahul.deshmukh\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files- 
   1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\014d6f324620f9879a964fbd74e0b4be\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69], 
   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

Gradle file shows mouse over error for :

> `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

`All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).<br> Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 27.1.1. Examples include com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 more... (Ctrl+F1)`

Not sure which library is conflicting with which one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your minimum and maximum sdk of version ?

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.<mycomp>.res.gmts"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }`

Comment: Have you tried running the `dependencies` task and seeing what `com.android.support` dependencies you have, as well as their versions?

Comment: Hi Peter, I did that and know the classes where 28.0.0-alpha1 is being used, but I am not sure how to remove that dependency or downgrade it to a lower version such as 27.1.1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change implementation order and also reduce versions of some of the dependencies as suggested by Izabela Orlowska in her answer.

Here are how my dependencies looks like now:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'
    api 'com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.14.0'
    api 'com.microsoft.services:sharepoint-services:1.0.0@aar'
    api 'com.microsoft.services:odata-engine-core:0.11.1'
    api 'com.microsoft.services:odata-engine-android-impl:0.11.1@aar'
    api 'com.microsoft.services.orc:orc-android:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I am off this hurdle now. Thank you all who commented and suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One of your dependencies is using resources that were only added in API 28 (P). Either find the library and use an older version, or update your compile SDK version to 'android P preview' (you can download it using the SDK manager).